# Regular expression to match any tiktok video id and url

Tags: node.js, regex, url

I'm trying to match all these with just one regex:

- `https://m.tiktok.com/h5/share/usr/6641141594707361797.html`
- `https://m.tiktok.com/v/6749869095467945218.html`
- `https://www.tiktok.com/embed/6567659045795758085`
- `https://www.tiktok.com/share/user/6567659045795758085`
- `https://www.tiktok.com/trending?shareId=6744531482393545985`
- `https://www.tiktok.com/@burntpizza89/video/7067695578729221378?is_copy_url=1&is_from_webapp=v1`
- `https://www.tiktok.com/@burntpizza89/video/is_copy_url=1&is_from_webapp=v1&item_id=7067695578729221378`
- `https://vm.tiktok.com/ZMF6rgvXY/`

And it works fine except for the last one. The current regex is:

```
"\bhttps?:\/\/(?:m|www|vm)\.tiktok\.com\/.*\b(?:(?:usr|v|embed|user|video)\/|\?shareId=|\&item_id=)(\d+)\b"gm
```

It's handling all these digits ids perfectly (.tiktok.com/@burntpizza89/video/**7067695578729221378**), but I also need to match somehow these types of links which contains some specific url (.tiktok.com/**ZMF6rgvXY**/) with just one regex. So for the match I would get or digit-only id, or the url which contains digits and characters.

Comment: How is that last ID characterized? Let's say at least 7 word characters, must contain either a digit or an upper alpha... you could add a second capturing group to your pattern, something like this demo: [`\bhttps?:\/\/(?:m|www|vm)\.tiktok\.com\/\S*?\b(?:(?:(?:usr|v|embed|user|video)\/|\?shareId=|\&item_id=)(\d+)|(?=\w{7})(\w*?[A-Z\d]\w*)(?=\s|\/$))\b`](https://regex101.com/r/Hx5RQN/1)

Comment: Wait, don't you just want to simply target *all* URIs that are of tiktok.com? Or really just those specific ones? Would be helpful if you also provided some list of things not to match but given some similarities.

Comment: You stated *"does not work for the last one"* - have you forgotten about this type of URI: `https://tiktok.com/embed/6567659045795758085` (without `www`)

Comment: Also `https://www.tiktok.com/@burntpizza89/video/is_copy_url=1&is_from_webapp=v1&item_id=7067695578729221378` is invalid - so your tests are kinda broken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this regex. Based on 
[bobble bubble](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5527985/bobble-bubble)'s regex

```
^.*https:\/\/(?:m|www|vm)?\.?tiktok\.com\/((?:.*\b(?:(?:usr|v|embed|user|video)\/|\?shareId=|\&item_id=)(\d+))|\w+)
```

https://regexr.com/7knot

Answer (score -1):

try the last part:

```
~https?://(?:www\.)?tiktok\.com/\S*/video/(\d+)|https?://(?:www\.)?vm.tiktok.com/\S*/~
```

Comment: [Demo of your suggestion](https://regex101.com/r/73sQM1/1) (a bit fixed). Please read the question again.